# Can you assign values to hidden fields in a form, through a php function, to be stored in a database?

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

1. I created a form you know; text fields, radio buttons and the submit button
2. within the said form, I have a div enclosing a section of the radio buttons hidden and a text field upon page load using inline CSS display:none;
3. If the end user chose yes, the hidden fields will be displayed using a jquery function. If the user chose No or Not Sure, the form will remain hidden or become hidden using the same jquery function.
4. If the user chose No or Not Sure, i want to automatically assign values for the hidden fields and store them in database.

Here is my form:

```
<div id = "relation" style = "display: none;">
    <p class= "form-p" >Who are you related o?</p>                    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="family" value="Bride" required />Bride
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="family" value="Groom" required />Groom
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="family" value="Friend" required />Friend
                </label>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $famErr;?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class = "form-p">Guests in your party, including yourself: </p>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name="num" placeholder = "0" required />
                <span class="error"><?php echo $numErr;?></span>
            </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of id relation-->
```

Here are the functions:

```
 // function to add RSVP user entry to the database
    public function user_attending_storage_RSVP($name, $email, $attend, $fam, $num){

        $replies = "INSERT INTO rsvp (name, attending, family, total) VALUES (:name,:attending,:family,:total)";

        try{
            $query = $this->conn->prepare($replies);
            $results = $query->execute(array(":name"=>$name, ":attending"=>$attend, ":family"=>$fam, ":total"=>$num));

        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   
    }

    // function to add RSVP user entry to the database
    public function user_not_attending_storage_RSVP($name, $email, $attend){



        $replies = "INSERT INTO rsvp (name, attending, family, total) VALUES (:name,:attending,:family,:total)";

        try{
            $query = $this->conn->prepare($replies);
            $results = $query->execute(array(":name"=>$name, ":attending"=>$attend, ":family"=>$fam, ":total"=>$num));  
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   
    }
```

Here's how I call the function on the webpage

```
 // check for data in fields
    if(isset($_POST['name']) ==true && isset($_POST['email']) ==true && isset($_POST['attending']) && isset($_POST['family']) && isset($_POST['num'])){

        $name=test_input($_POST['name']);
        $email=test_input($_POST['email']);
        $attend=test_input($_POST['attending']);
        $fam=test_input($_POST['family']);
        $num=test_input($_POST['num']);

        if($attend == "No" || $attend == "Not Sure"){

            $fam = "nothing";
            $num = 0;

            //inserting user data from form into database
            $genQuery->user_Not_attending_storage_RSVP($name, $email, $attend);

        }
        else{
            //inserting user data from form into database
            $genQuery->user_attending_storage_RSVP($name, $email, $attend, $fam, $num);
        }

        // send mail to user
        $genQuery->user_invite_confirmation_RSVP($name, $email, $attend,$fam, $num);


    }
```

Comment: You could try if($('#input_id).val() == 'no' || $('#input_id).val() == 'not sure'){$('#input_id_you_want_to_change).val('Default value')}

Comment: @Niall That could be a nice solution but then this is javaScript. How would I use javaScript to store this data in the database?

Comment: So what you want to do is store it in the database using javascript? Well then you can't. You need a combination of javascript and php. Use : if(getElementById('input_id').value() == 'no' || getElementById('user_id') == 'not sure'){getElementById('input_you_want_to_change).value('Defualt value')}. To change the values in the inputs and then use php to store it in the database as the value is now changed.

Comment: no i'm not exactly looking for a way to store the data specifically with javascript, just want the data to get stored. Thanks alot though I'm gonna try your your approach.

Comment: What are you doing with the form if it's not posting it to the server ?? When you submit it, you can make what you want with these data. Also, you could use ajax to persist user choices each time a change is made on "Are you sure". But IMO it's a waste of resources.

Comment: I will add my comment as an answer. Please accept it as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getElementById() method...

```
if(getElementById('input_id').value() == 'no' || getElementById('user_id').value() == 'not sure'){getElementById('input_you_want_to_change).value('Defualt value')}
```

This will change the value if the user selects no or not sure. Then use PHP to store this new value in the database.